# Setting's "Search" function doesn't work properly on Android N Preview 3

Tags: settings, search, 7.0-nougat, developer-preview

In settings of Android phone, there is a search button in the Action Bar and it cannot give me what I want to search. I find it works sometimes but 90% it doesn't. The 2nd image shows the very irrelevant results.

For example, I enter `battery` to search for battery settings, it gives me nothing.

My question is: how to fix it?

---

[image: search settings]

And result when enter `ba`:

[image]

Comment: Is this Android N? It works for me on a Nexus 6P with Android N: http://imgur.com/oEA8ZIZ

Comment: I have one M and one N with the same symptom.

Comment: It works on Moto X play stock 6.0.1.  Two things I noticed 1. Typing 'Battery'  *letter by letter* reveals all battery  related things 2. If your keyboard is prompting you *battery* and you select it make sure there is **no space** after the word (if there is a space it shows nothing, deleting space by back arrow reveals). In both cases,  I see *Battery, Battery saver, Battery optimisation, Adaptive brightness and battery level* as search results

Comment: It searches only for subgroups in my N. That bug I know.

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen What ROM/Device? From reading the answers and comments, this sure sounds like a ROM code problem and should be handled by the ROM developer(s).

Comment: It is the N on Nexus 6P

Comment: I have a very similar issue, but I was on custom ROM. So, I couldn't tell if this was ROM or Marshmallow issue.

Comment: This is the N Preview 3, released by Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the system bug. Try clearing **cache** and **dalvik cache**. If problem presist try **factory data reset**. If still presist, then its a Rom bug. If it is, then wait for the update for fix.

Comment: I tried it before: reset to factory/re-install rom/clear cache... The same results: enter `B` it can give `bluetooth` but no `battery` in the result section

Comment: Yes! After the update to Beta, the search function works again

Answer (score 5):

I cleared data and cache from settings app and it's worked for me. Not factory reset and clear cache from recovery. I went into settings>apps>allaps,settings>storage and clear cache and data

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me on Android 9 was: Find system app "Settings Suggestions", open app info, press force stop, press storage and hit clear cache and clear storage buttons.

Comment: _Settings Suggestions_ is a system app: in order to show it in the _All Apps_ list you need to tap on the _more options_ icon (three vertical dots, aka _kebab menu_) in the top right corner of the screen and select "Show system".

Comment: Thanks! After forcing stop worked. But

Comment: Thanks. Forcing stop works! But not sure if the problem will return?

Comment: Problem returned next day! Now doesn't work anymore

Comment: Only works temporary, the issue returned the next day and forcing stop no longer work

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like search may be disabled for you.

Go to your Settings > Apps > swipe to the “ALL” tab > select “Google Search” > press “Enable”.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. All apps are enabled in this directory!